# How to make a button with more information in android studio

Tags: android, button, layout

I'm trying to develop a button that has more than just an text information + an icon, but I don't know how can I make this, I want to make as this layout image right here:

[Exepected Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lhFP.png)

I've already started to make it but I don't know how to finish, should I use a button? or try to make a container to store all information?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Olá usuário!"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView20" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logotechtablecolorida"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView29"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="Escolha seu restaurante e faça seu pedido"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtUsuario" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Buttons only hold text.  ImageButton holds only an image.  If neither of those is what you want, you're probably better off building something custom.  A button is really just a text view with a built in background drawable that does the touch animation.

Comment: Oh okay then, I will find another solution thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any layout (ConstraintLayout, LinearLayout) and set a click listener to them.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/twoLinesButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the first line"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the second line"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in your code, attach a click listener to the view.

```
val twoLinesButton = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.twoLinesButton)
twoLinesButton.setOnClickListener {
    //Handle the click action
}
```